# YouTube: Load denied by X-Frame-Options; does not permit cross-origin framing?

Tags: video, cross-domain, x-frame-options

I got error a [`Load denied by X-Frame-Options` error for a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2FpyDdG8PU&feature=youtu.be).

Does YouTube not permit cross-origin framing?

I am new to Angular JS. I have allowed `X-Frame-Options` in Header PHP file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more details of what you're doing and what the problems are, what you've done to fix them, what the new problems were etc. I.e. the basic stuff that SO questions **should** have.

Comment: <div ng-controller="Homevideo" >  
    <div ng-repeat="s in  test">{{s}}
     <iframe width="420" height="345" ng-src="{{s}}"> </iframe>
</div>   Html code

Comment: <script>
angular.module('Video', [
'Video.controllers'
]);

angular.module('Video.controllers', [])

.controller('Homevideo', ['$scope', "$http",'$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
$http.get("http://persistentdemo.com/webservices/ajax/indore_flash.php")
      .success(function (response)
      {
        $scope.videoarray = response.Video_gallery
       
         
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.videoarray.length;i++){
           $scope.test[i] = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.videoarray[i].video_url);
         
          
        }
      });
      $scope.test=[];
}]);
</script>

Comment: I want Play multiple video in angular js on every browser.. I have shered the link http://persistentdemo.com/test1/. It Did work on Firefox. Please help me.  This is My webservice in json Format http://persistentdemo.com/webservices/ajax/indore_flash.php